# Connector identification (multipin connector for automotive touchscreen)

Tags: connector, automotive, touchscreen, device

This connector is from a device connected to the touch screen in the car. This device is chinese, so I'm having trouble locating information about any part number or name.

The connector has 4 wires cut and the matching pins in the connector are missing, so the connector needs to be replaced.

I'll appreciate any information you can provide.

Here are the photos:

- cable connector:
  [image: cable connector 1]
  [image: cable connector 2]
- port in the pcb of the touchscreen:
  [image: pcb connector 1]
  [image: pcb connector 2]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've counted the pins, its 41 pin. I googled "41 pin" and it give me an identical photo of mine!
[photo](https://goo.gl/images/w78rjN)

Comment: here is another [one](https://goo.gl/images/nyWmQ7). It is called "41 pin lvds lcd cable" and it is available in online markets.

Answer (score 0):

I've counted the pins, its 41 pin. I googled "41 pin" and it give me an identical photo of mine!

[image: 1st photo]

and here is another one:
[image: 2nd photo]

it is called "41 pin lvds lcd cable" and it's available online.